# Make an absolute div relevant to another specific div

Tags: css

Assuming that I have simple absolute element:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
.abs {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="abs"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make the `abs` class relative to the `body` or any other element than `.container` using CSS only without having to change the layout? I ask this question because I am dynamically injecting elements in a third party UI library whose layout I cannot change.

UPDATE:

- I can't teleport in this case.
- I can't change the container's style as it is part of a library that I am not allowed to tweak.

Comment: can you remove the position: relative;  from .abs parent elements ?

Comment: by changing relative to static position like this  .container {position: static;}

Comment: @ShahilMishra: No as I said it is managed by a third party UI library!

Comment: you can update third party css at your local as well.
try to find the class of the css in current library and override the same css locally with !important tag. I hope it will work

Comment: position:fixed instead of absolute. If you cannot do this as well then you have no way to achieve what you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Position fixed means `Fixed` and not absolute

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9nj6wL15/